# Table module samples

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, sample

I'm looking for some good open-source sample applications that use the Table Module pattern to organize the business logic (can be any language).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

How about the [App Pattern: Four-Tier Web Application Scenario (Table Module)](http://apparch.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=App%20Pattern%20-%20Four-Tier%20Web%20Application%20Scenario%20%28Table%20Module)
 from codeplex? I know this is an old post, but I stumbled across it whilst searching for some similar stuff for myself. So I thought an answer might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

By [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html):

> A Table Module organizes domain logic
>   with one class per table in the
>   data-base, and a single instance of a
>   class contains the various procedures
>   that will act on the data.

I don't have any open source examples for you, BUT I think it is quite self-explanatory and easy to grasp.

Here are the signs of this pattern:

1. One class per table
2. Low code reuse
3. High coupling
4. Low cohesion

I think that it will be easier to find that code in old legacy code than in open source projects.